# Laravel 5.5 - Form Request Failed Validation Response with dontFlash

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.5

In laravel 5.2 I was able to override the response on a individual form request as follows and use the `dontFlash` property to exclude flashing certain fields:

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
    // action is a hidden form input
    $this->redirect = $this->getRedirectUrl() . '#' . $this->action;
    $this->errorBag = $this->action;
    $this->dontFlash[] = 'action';

    if ($this->ajax() || $this->wantsJson()) {
        return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
    }
    return $this->redirector->to($this->getRedirectUrl())
        ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
        ->withErrors($errors, $this->errorBag);
}
```

In laravel 5.5 the `dontflash` property has been removed and we are advised to override the `failedvalidation` method instead as follows:

```
protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
{
   $this->redirect = $this->getRedirectUrl() . '#' . $this->action;
   $this->errorBag = $this->action;
   $this->dontFlash[] = 'action';

    throw (new ValidationException($validator))
        ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
        ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
}
```

So my question is how can I exclude flashing certain field - the above throws error:

```
Indirect modification of overloaded property 
App\Http\Requests\MyFormRequest::$dontFlash has no effect
```

The only way I can think of is by adding the field name to the `dontFlash` property inside `exceptions\handler.php` file

But then it would take effect for every form which included a field with that name which is not the behaviour I want.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Comment: Can we see the rule that you have applied for it? perhaps it would be best to alter the rule with something like `require_if`, etc.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Basically I have several forms on the page with a hidden field named `action` but with different values to indicate which form was submitted e.g. `<input name="action" type="hidden" value="personalDetails">`. This is also used to append anchor tag to url to show/hide the form - the forms are inside accordians. The `action` field has no rule.

Comment: Did you find a workaround? I too have a similar issue.